# How to pass in coordinates to LatLng function in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in coordinates to the L.LatLng function in leaflet so that it can map the coordinates.

I can successfully load in the data, and it looks like this:

```
//This is the structure of the geojson data, as an example
var SanFranciscoData = {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-96.97593699999999,32.889954000000046]}

//Load in the geojson
d3.json("data/dataPoints.json", function(SFData) {
        var SFData = SanFranciscoData.features
        })

    //pass in coordinates to the L.LatLng leaflet function
    SFData.forEach(function(d) {
        d.latLong = new L.LatLng(d.features.geometry.coordinates[1],
                                d.features.geometry.coordinates[0]);
         })
```

I've also tried, as I've seen done in examples:

```
var coords = SFData.feature.geometry.coordinates;
```

Both methods above give the same result: the coordinates are undefined. What am I doing wrong?  I'm not sure how to access the coordinates array using object notation in order to access the lat / longs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. this worked:

```
SFData.forEach(function(d) {
        var coords = d.geometry.coordinates
        console.log(coords)
        d.latLong = new L.LatLng(coords[1],
                                coords[0]);

    })
```

Seems as if coordinates needed to be defined withing the .forEach function!

Comment: In your question you are trying to access `SFData.feature.geometry.coordinates` while in your answer you access `SFData.geometry.coordinates`

Comment: Correct.  var SFData = SanFranciscoData.features .  I guess I'm still confused about what d means?  This is in d3.js.  Is d just a placeholder?  I'm generally very ignorant about how the object notation works here so any help appreciated.